# Function that takes a string as input and counts the number of times the vowel occurs in the string

Tags: python

So I am very new to python and am in the process of learning the basics. I am trying to create a function the counts the number of vowels in a string and returns how many times each vowel occurs in the string. For example if I gave it this input, this is what it would print out.

```
   >>>countVowels('Le Tour de France') 
       a, e, i, o, and u appear, respectively, 1,3,0,1,1 times.
```

I made this helper function to use, but then I'm not exactly sure how to use it.

```
def find_vowels(sentence):
count = 0
vowels = "aeiuoAEIOU"
for letter in sentence:
    if letter in vowels:
        count += 1
print count
```

And then I thought that maybe I could use formatting to get them in the write places, but I am not sure the notation that would be used for example, one of the lines for the function could be:

```
   'a, , i, o, and u appear, respectively, {(count1)}, {(count2)}, {(count3)}, {(count4)}, {(count5)} times'
```

I am not sure how I would be able to fit the above in the function.

Comment: hmm i recall this example from a class i took a bit ago, and if the book is written by Dr. Perkovic I also know that this is a homework problem (to get the formatting right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use a dictionary to store the values, since if you directly add the counts you lose information about exactly which vowel you are counting.

```
def countVowels(s):
    s = s.lower() #so you don't have to worry about upper and lower cases
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    return {vowel:s.count(vowel) for vowel in vowels} #a bit inefficient, but easy to understand
```

An alternate method would be:

```
def countVowels(s):
    s = s.lower()
    vowels = {'a':0,'e':0,'i':0,'o':0,'u':0}
    for char in s:
        if char in vowels:
            vowels[char]+=1
    return vowels
```

to print this, you would do this:

```
def printResults(result_dict):
    print "a, e, i, o, u, appear, respectively, {a},{e},{i},{o},{u} times".format(**result_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier answer would be to use the Counter class.

```
def count_vowels(s):
    from collections import Counter
    #Creates a Counter c, holding the number of occurrences of each letter 
    c = Counter(s.lower())
    #Returns a dictionary holding the counts of each vowel
    return {vowel:c[vowel] for vowel in 'aeiou'}
```

Comment: Admittedly, this would be easier, but it seems to both violate the purpose of the assignment (if it is dictionary assignment and looping) as well as take up more space than needed.

Comment: The gain in simplicity far outweighs the marginal increase in size. The largest it could get is 127, unless you get into unicode in which case you're right. I've always thought that learning to do stuff manually is great, as long as you know the proper/canonical/sensible way to do it. One of the great things about python is that you almost never have to use loops. Learning to write python in a C-like way is about as pointless as turning a screw with your thumb whilst holding a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

```
a =input("Enter string: ")
vowels = sum([a.lower().count(i) for i in "aeiou"])
print(vowels)
```

This also works. dont know if it is more or less efficient. it makes list for each of aeiou and sums it